# Segment tree in Python3

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, tree

I've implemented a Segment Tree in Python3:

```
import math

INF = int(2e9)


class SegmentTreeNode:
    def __init__(self, l, r, v=INF):
        self.left = l
        self.right = r
        self.value = v

    def merge(self, left, right):
        if left is not None and right is not None:
            self.value = min(left.value, right.value)
        elif left is None and right is None:
            self.value = INF
        elif left is None:
            self.value = right.value
        else:
            self.value = left.value


class SegmentTree:
    def __init__(self, a):
        n = len(a)
        power = math.ceil(math.log(n, 2))
        total = 2 ** (power + 1)
        self.__tree = [None] * int(total)
        self.__leaf_length = int(total/2)-1
        self.__build(1, 0, self.__leaf_length, a)

    def __build(self, node, l, r, a):
        if l == r:
            self.__tree[node] = SegmentTreeNode(l, r)
            try:
                self.__tree[node].value = a[l]
            except IndexError:
                self.__tree[node].value = INF
            return
        leftchild = 2 * node
        rightchild = leftchild + 1
        mid = (l + r) // 2
        self.__build(leftchild, l, mid, a)
        self.__build(rightchild, mid + 1, r, a)
        self.__tree[node] = SegmentTreeNode(l, r)
        l = self.__tree[leftchild]
        r = self.__tree[rightchild]
        self.__tree[node].merge(l, r)

    def __query(self, node, l, r, i, j):
        if l >= i and r <= j:
            return self.__tree[node]
        elif j < l or i > r:
            return None
        else:
            leftchild = 2 * node
            rightchild = leftchild + 1
            mid = (l + r) // 2
            l = self.__query(leftchild, l, mid, i, j)
            r = self.__query(rightchild, mid + 1, r, i, j)
            if l is not None and r is not None:
                return SegmentTreeNode(-1, -1, min(l.value, r.value))
            elif l is None and r is None:
                return SegmentTreeNode(-1, -1, INF)
            elif l is None:
                return SegmentTreeNode(-1, -1, r.value)
            else:
                return SegmentTreeNode(-1, -1, l.value)

    def query(self, i, j): 
        return self.__query(1, 0, self.__leaf_length, i, j)

    def __update(self, node, l, r, i, v):
        if l == i and r == i:
            self.__tree[node].value = v
        elif i < l or i > r:
            return None
        else:
            leftchild = 2 * node
            rightchild = leftchild + 1
            mid = (l + r) // 2
            self.__update(leftchild, l, mid, i, v)
            self.__update(rightchild, mid + 1, r, i, v)
            l = self.__tree[leftchild]
            r = self.__tree[rightchild]
            self.__tree[node].merge(l, r)

    def update(self, i, value):
        self.__update(1, 0, self.__leaf_length, i, value)

in_n, in_m = map(int, input().rsplit())
in_array = list(map(int, input().rsplit()))
segment_tree = SegmentTree(in_array)

for row in range(in_m):
    command = input().rsplit()
    x, y = map(int, command[1:])
    if command[0] == 'Min':
        print(segment_tree.query(x - 1, y - 1).value)
    else:
        segment_tree.update(x-1, y)
```

I take `n` and `m` from `stdin` after I read an `array[n]`. And then I read *m* operations 
"Set I X" or "Min L R".

Here is profiler log for relevant testcase:

```
 ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
 2969521/49877    3.871    0.000    4.753    0.000 test.py:51(__query)
 1754305/50123    1.792    0.000    2.685    0.000 test.py:74(__update)
       1721965    0.829    0.000    0.829    0.000 test.py:8(__init__)
        983162    0.732    0.000    1.081    0.000 test.py:13(merge)
       1619481    0.576    0.000    0.576    0.000 {built-in method min}
        100002    0.548    0.000    0.551    0.000 {built-in method input}
      262143/1    0.545    0.000    0.907    0.907 test.py:33(__build)
             1    0.429    0.429    9.550    9.550 test.py:1(<module>)
         49877    0.076    0.000    0.076    0.000 {built-in method print}
        100002    0.068    0.000    0.068    0.000 {method 'rsplit' of 'str' objects}
         49877    0.045    0.000    4.799    0.000 test.py:71(query)
         50123    0.034    0.000    2.719    0.000 test.py:89(update)
           339    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {built-in method utf_8_decode}
             1    0.002    0.002    0.908    0.908 test.py:25(__init__)
           339    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 codecs.py:310(decode)
             2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method __build_class__}
             1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method init_builtin}
```

I guess the problem is in query function. How can it be improved? Any ideas? 
Here is a relevant [test-case](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4JKldGNJPOTaGZXY3RJZmhEVGc/edit?usp=sharing). I need to achieve the result at least 2 times faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SegmentTreeNode` objects have three attributes: `left`, `right` and `value`, but only `value` is ever used. Using plain integers instead of custom objects should speed things up, as it avoids overhead both in object creation and in attribute access.

Comment: Yeah. You are right.This simple change speeds up code significantly. It can be said that the problem is solved.